# How do you comment out a rule in Proguard.cfg?

Tags: android, proguard

What syntax is used to comment out a proguard rule inside Proguard.cfg?  Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hash symbols.

```
# This is a comment.  The 3 lines below are not.
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity { 
       public void *(android.view.View); 
}
```

Comment: Good to know, but can you cite a source?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual

> You can add comments in a configuration file, starting with a # character and continuing until the end of the line.

Example

```
# This is a comment
```

Manual Link Here

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html